# C# XNA code on the web for a standard browser

Tags: c#, browser, web, xna, executable

Apparently, there is a way to add C# XNA projects to websites such that they can be viewed on the site from a normal web browser, presumably there are concessions to safety that the browser will enforce.

How is this done?

edit: I think the C# project might only ever runs on the server, the client being sent something it can understand.

Comment: Off the top of my head, you can do it with a windows XBAP application (Windows Internet Explorer only I think), or you could leverage Silverlight 5's 3D capabilities.

Comment: My projects are 2D graphically. Everyone uses Firefox or Chrome, I presumed it was converted into JS somehow or similar, apparently the server does something.

Comment: Then you'll have to be more specific; it sounds like you're talking about a particular kind of product that already exists? What is the "apparent way to add" that you're talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is http://jsil.org which will convert a compiled .Net application into a client side Javascript "app" ... and has been demonstrated to work rather successfully on XNA games.

It only handles 2D stuff and sound is / was needing to manually rewritten last time I checked but it does a pretty impressive job from what I've seen of it.

It should be noted that whilst this may get the job done, it's certainly not going to produce JS that is anywhere near the quality (i.e. maintainability) of a game that was written in JS from the start (using something like three.js or easle.js)... so if this for a commercial product, you may wish to explore rewriting / porting the game specifically for web as a serious alternative.

Comment: Or keep in the main source in dot net. tyvm I'm trying it out now.

Comment: I'm not sure how to have it perform the convertion, the site isn't helpful on this. I've downloaded it from 'https://github.com/kevingadd/JSIL.git' as a zip file and extracted the files. There was no executible but there was a .sln, this didn't open when opened but using 'file -> open' from inside Visual (Studio) C# worked, however there are 968 errors and I havn't even told it what solution to convert yet. How are you suposed to get it working?

Comment: I'd suggest following the wiki instructions and see how far that takes you. https://github.com/kevingadd/JSIL/wiki

Comment: ty, I've now tried this. I'm not sure what GIT is, and it looks like a Linux thing, thankfully it seems just to be about downloading JSIL and I've done that part already. When running the sln I get these errors http://pastebin.com/fuK4YwQi, then when running, these ones http://pastebin.com/1773nYdH.

Comment: This is ridiculous, apparently all I need is the one file JSILc.exe I can't believe they won't just provide it.

Comment: It's been quite some time since I last played with it. Maybe searching https://github.com/kevingadd/JSIL/issues will provide some answers.

Comment: It was very complicated, but I've got JSIL.exe and am trying to get things working, tyvm lzcd.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible without a plugin. The plugin would work only on Windows, obviously, since XNA is built on DirectX.

There's no plugin that currently does this, to my knowledge.

It's not difficult to write a plugin, however, you'd have to do this for each browser you want the plugin to run in.

If you want your game content on the web, a better route is probably [HTML5 and its Canvas functionality](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/web-roundups/21-ridiculously-impressive-html5-canvas-experiments/), which works on all modern browsers. You might be interested in [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davrous/archive/2011/09/09/html5-platformer-the-complete-port-of-the-xna-game-to-lt-canvas-gt-with-easeljs.aspx), which discusses porting a 2D XNA game to HTML5 Canvas.

If you need 3D support, you could go the HTML5 WebGL route, although Internet Explorer doesn't support it.

Comment: Defeats the point if an executable (or plugin) must be installed, and I know there is some way of doing this better.

Comment: XNA is DirectX + Managed Code. Browsers don't know how to run that, so you'll need a plugin that tells browsers how to render that. There's really no way around that. If you don't want to have to install a plugin, you should be using HTML5, not XNA.

Answer (score 0):

Probably what you want is [Google Native Client (NaCl)](https://developers.google.com/native-client/). I haven't played with it (yet), but as far as I know, some game engines like Unity works on it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Does this only work when the viewer of your content has Chrome? In other respects it looks great, I can't see why it got a downvote.

Comment: I haven't digged at the technology, but I suspect it works only on Chrome. But I believe this is a very consistent technology and (they way I see) it may become the future of the web. Thank you for your vote!